# Knockout mapping is not updating my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm having trouble with a knockout model that is not binding on a subscribed update. I have a C# MVC page that delivers a model to the template which is parsed to Json and delivered raw as part of a ViewModel assignment for `ko.applyBindings`. I have a subscription to an observable that calls a method to perform an update of the viewModel's data. Irrelevant stuff pulled out and renamed for example usage:

```
var myViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.CurrentPage = ko.observable();
    self.SomeComplexArray= ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Pager().CurrentPage.subscribe(function (newPage) {
        self.UpdateMyViewModel(newPage);
    });

    self.UpdateMyViewModel= function (newPage) {
        var postData = { PageNumber: newPage };
        $.post('/Article/GetMyModelSearchByPage', postData, function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);;
        });
};
```

When I perform logging, I can see all of the data, and it all looks correct. The same method is used to produce both the initial model and the updated model. I've used this technique on other pages and it worked flawlessly each time. In this case however, I'm looking for it to bind/update `SomeComplexArray`, and that's  just not happening. If I attempt to do it manually, I don't get a proper bind on the array I get blank. I'm wondering if there is something obvious that I'm doing wrong that I'm just flat out missing.

**Edit:** I don't know that ko.mapping can be pointed to as the culprit. Standard model changes are also not affecting the interface. Here is something that is not working in a bound sense. I have a p element with visible bound to the length of the array and a div element with a click bound to a function that pops items off of SomeComplexArray. I can see in the console log that it is performing its function (and subsequent clicks result in 'undefined' not having that function). However, the p element never displays. The initial array has only 2 items so a single click empties it:

```
<p data-bind="visible: SomeComplexArray().length === 0">nothing found</p>


<div data-bind="click: function() { UpdateArray(); }">try it manually</div>


-- in js model
self.UpdateArray = function () {
        console.log(self.SomeComplexArray());
        console.log(self.SomeComplexArray().pop());
        console.log(self.SomeComplexArray());
        console.log(self.SomeComplexArray().pop());
        console.log(self.SomeComplexArray());
});
```

**Edit 2:** from the comment @Matt Burland, I've modified how the pop is called and the manual method now works to modify the elements dynamically. However, the ko.mapping is still not functioning as I would expect. In a test, I did a console.log of a specific row before calling ko.mapping and after. No change was made to the observableArray.

Comment: What does data look like? Is it a JavaScript object?

Comment: @m.casey: It's a POCO in JSON format. Using `JSON.parse()` on it provides a properly formatted and accessible object.

Comment: Reason why I ask, ko.mapping.fromJS() expects that 'data' should be a JavaScript object, so if we're passing 'data' and 'data' is still a JSON object at the time, it wouldn't work, right? Also, not sure if this is just a copy/paste issue, but there's a syntax error at the end of the mapping statement and a missing '}' after the $.post function.

Comment: @m.casey: The object that is returned from the controller is identical (with the exception of the data in it) to the one that loads on page load. If the object was malformed in anyway it would have given me an error in the console.log (which it did several times as I tried various ideas to get it to work).

Comment: Why are you not using self.FreakyArray=ko.observableArray([]) ?

Comment: @johnSmith: An oversight, but in the initial load, ko.mapping is taking care of that. Making this change does not alter the result.

Comment: @JoelEtherton is that possible to share your code how you are updating your SomeComplexArray?

Comment: @ToughCoder: Originally I was trying to get ko.mapping to perform the update. The next thing I tried was to try `.removeAll` on it. This last time I simply have a button with a click event bound on a div element. It calls a function in the viewmodel that does `self.SomeComplexArray().pop()`. I have console.log messages in between all of the statements. The pop occurs properly, SomeComplexArray empties, no change in the bound interface occurs. Also of note, one of the functions used in a visible binding gets called on page load, but after the pop statements does not get called again.

Comment: Replace `self.SomeComplexArray().pop()` with `self.SomeComplexArray.pop()` and your edit will work. When you do `self.SomeComplexArray()` you get back the regular JS array that is *not* observable. If you want KO to see changes to your array you have to work with the observable array itself and it's functions. See: http://jsfiddle.net/AdGe3/

Comment: Dynamite, good catch. That worked to get my "manual" method of updating the observableArray functioning. However, returning to the ko.mapping method, it still fails to perform the update.

Comment: In the `ko.mapping`, why are you passing an empty object as the second parameter? Shouldn't it be `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self);` as per the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). If that's not working, can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem? You don't need to do the `.ajax` part, it should be enough to just pass any old object to `ko.mapping`

Comment: @MattBurland: I had it without the empty object, and when that didn't work I read several articles and answers that indicated the empty object was necessary. I also have that pattern working, however, with several other viewmodels in other pages. None of them has an issue with the ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why, but it would seem that ko.mapping is having difficulty remapping the viewmodel at all. Since none of the fields are being mapped into `self` my assumption is that there is an exception occurring somewhere that ko.mapping is simply swallowing or it is not being reported for some other reason. Given that I could manually manipulate the array with a helpful tip from @MattBurland, I decided to backtrack a bit and update only the elements that needed to change directly on the data load. I ended up creating an `Init` function for my viewModel and using ko.mapping to populate the items directly there:

```
self.Init = function (jsonData) {
    self.CurrentPage(0);
    self.Items(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData.Items)());
    self.TotalItems(jsonData.TotalItems);
    // More stuff below here not relevant to question
}
```

The primary difference here is that the ko.mapping.fromJS result needed to be called as a function before the observableArray would recognize it as such. Given that this worked and that my controller would be providing an identical object back during the AJAX request, it was almost copy/past:

```
self.UpdateMyViewModel= function (newPage) {
    var postData = { PageNumber: newPage };
    $.post('/Article/GetMyModelSearchByPage', postData, function (data) {
        self.Items(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(data).Items)());
    });
};
```

This is probably not ideal for most situations, but since there is not a large manipulation of the viewModel occurring during the update this provides a working solution. I would still like to know why ko.mapping would not remap the viewModel at the top level, but in retrospect it probably would have been a disaster anyway since there was "modified" data in the viewModel that the server would have had to replace. This solution is quick and simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test of your knockout situation in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ab2/2/).

You have to call your array function without paranthesis. I tested this part:

```
self.UpdateArray = function () {

        self.SomeComplexArray.pop();

};
```

It seems to be working on JSFiddle side.

Comment: After some comments from @MattBurland this manual test does work. However, the original ko.mapping still fails to function properly.

Comment: @JoelEtherton, I found your problem. You can check my updated answer.

Comment: That's not the problem. That was just something I was using to test the updating of the interface, and like I said, comments from MattBurland helped me correct that. The problem lies with the fact that ko.mapping is not functioning as defined in the initial code sample.